# Is there a trick to making Adobe products play nice with Mission Control?

Tags: mission-control, window-manager, adobe

I really love Mission Control but at times some of my programs (Illustrator and Photoshop in particular) won't always minimize to the Mission Control view.

Comment: Has Adobe even released a version of their creative suite software that takes advantage of full screen / mission control changes introduced in Lion? http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/905/cpsid_90508.html?promoid=JBQYW#main_Support_for_Mac_OS_10_7_new_features

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to Adobe's support pages, more development is needed to support all the features of 10.7 like "Autosave, Restore, Versioning, Full Screen Mode, and more multi-touch gestures."  I think Mission Control is part of this.